# Cannot call IVirtualButtonEventHandler Vuforia 5.0.10

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Im using Unity 4.7.0 and Vuforia 5.0.10, i cannot call the `IVirtualButtonEventHandler`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class VBEventHandler : MonoBehaviour, IVirtualButtonEventHandler 
{

}
```

Comment: Why can't you? Are you getting a compilation error? If so what?

Comment: it calls you ... include your code

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this, hope you're still using Unity & Vuforia. You need to add using Vuforia to make the call.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Vuforia;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Register the Virtual Button:**

To add a virtual button to an image target, add the VirtualButton element and its attributes to the ImageTarget element in the .xml file.

XML Attributes:

1. Name - a unique name for the button
2. Rectangle - defined by the four corners of the rectangle in the
   target's coordinate space
3. Enabled - a boolean indicating whether the button should be enabled
   by default
4. Sensitivity - HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW sensitivity to occlusion

---

**After Registering Virtual Button Code is simple then:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Vuforia;
    public class Custom_VirtualButton : MonoBehaviour, IVirtualButtonEventHandler
    {
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {

    // here it finds any VirtualButton Attached to the ImageTarget and register it's event handler and in the
    //OnButtonPressed and OnButtonReleased methods you can handle different buttons Click state
    //via "vb.VirtualButtonName" variable and do some really awesome stuff with it.
            VirtualButtonBehaviour[] vbs = GetComponentsInChildren<VirtualButtonBehaviour>();
            foreach (VirtualButtonBehaviour item in vbs)
            {
                item.RegisterEventHandler(this);
            }

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {

        }


        #region VirtualButton

        public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb)
        {
            Debug.Log("Helllllloooooooooo");
        }

        public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb)
        {
            Debug.Log("Goooooodbyeeee");
        }

        #endregion //VirtualButton
    }
```